# how to iterate over awk result

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following string that I want to retrieve a specific ID for `eu-central-1` only:

`ca-central-1:ami-aaaa,eu-central-1:ami-bbbb,eu-north-1:ami-cccc,eu-west-1:ami-dddd`

so what I want as an output is: `ami-bbbb`

The way I am doing it right now is:

```
echo a-central-1:ami-aaaa,eu-central-1:ami-bbbb,eu-north-1:ami-cccc,eu-west-1:ami-dddd |
awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' |
awk -F':' '{print $2}'
```

The problem with this approach is that I am explicity specifying that `eu-central-1` is the second ($2) result for the first `awk` call, but sometimes they might in different order, so I might need to iterate over this result. Is it possible to achieve this in one line, and without knowing before hand in which place in the string `eu-central-1:ami-bbbb` will land?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep` like so:

```
echo your_string | grep -Po '\beu-central-1:\K[^,]+'
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only, 1 match/line, not the entire lines.

`\b` : Word boundary.
`\K` : Pretend that the match starts at this point. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.
`[^,]+` : Any characters that are not a comma, one or more occurrences.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Comment: If your `grep` doesn't support `-P` and you don't have `pcregrep` drop the `\K` and append  `| cut -d: -f2`.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I'd prefer `grep` as in [Timur Shtatland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65365848/6770384). But for completeness here is an alternative:</sub>

You can set `awk`'s record separator (linebreak by default) and then only print that record starting with `eu-central-1`.

```
awk -F: -v RS=, '$1 == "eu-central-1" { print $2 }'
```

Comment: That would print an extra newline if `eu-central-1:foo` was the last thing on the input line.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. If such a problem occurs you could fix it using `RS=',|\n'`. But I'm not sure about the input format. Maybe linebreaks are allowed as "regular" symbols inside a single field. OP has to decide on this. However, depending on the input, there is most definitely always a linebreak at the very end.

Comment: Yes, you could use `RS=',|\n'` (or even just `RS='[,\n]'`) but then it'd be gawk-specific (which might be OK).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed or OSX/BSD sed for `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^|.*,)eu-central-1:([^,]*).*/\2/' file
ami-bbbb
```

Answer (score 0):

One `sed` idea:

```
id='eu-central-1'

# desired id in middle of input string:

echo 'a-central-1:ami-aaaa,eu-central-1:ami-bbbb,eu-north-1:ami-cccc,eu-west-1:ami-dddd' | \
sed -En "s/^(.*,)*${id}:([^,]*)(,.*)*$/\2/p"
```

Where:

- `-En` - enable extended regex support
- `^(.*,)*` - [capture group #1] - matches start of line plus zero or more instances of characters ending with a comma (`,`)
- `^(.*,)*${id}:` - capture group #1 followed by `${id}` + `:`
- `([^,]*)` - [capture group #2] - matches everything up to, but not including, the next comma (`,`)
- `(,.*)*$` - [capture group #3] - matches zero or more instances of comma followed by other characters to end of line
- `\2/p` - print capture group #2

Alternatively, using a here-string to eliminate the pipe/sub-process call:

```
id='eu-central-1'

# desired id at start of input string:

sed -En "s/^(.*,)*${id}:([^,]*)(,.*)*$/\2/p"  <<< 'eu-central-1:ami-bbbb,a-central-1:ami-aaaa,eu-north-1:ami-cccc,eu-west-1:ami-dddd'

# desired id at end of input string:

sed -En "s/^(.*,)*${id}:([^,]*)(,.*)*$/\2/p"  <<< 'a-central-1:ami-aaaa,eu-north-1:ami-cccc,eu-west-1:ami-dddd,eu-central-1:ami-bbbb'
```

All three generate:

```
ami-bbbb
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining `,` as line (record) separator and `:` as field separator, a simple condition over `$1` prints the result.

```
echo -n a-central-1:ami-aaaa,eu-central-1:ami-bbbb,eu-north-1:ami-cccc,eu-west-1:ami-dddd |
awk 'BEGIN{RS=","; FS=":"}$1=="eu-central-1"{print $2}'
```

Comment: That's the same answer [@Socowi gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65365887/1745001) 10 hours earlier and so has the same issue that it would print an extra newline if `eu-central-1:foo` was the last thing on the input line.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't notice his answer. Do you mean it will also print `foo`? I didn't mean to deal with multiple occurrences of `eu-central-1`, but it can be easily fixed.

Comment: No, I mean it will print `foo\n\n` instead of just `foo\n` since the `\n` at the end of the input will be part of `$2` since it's not consumed as the `RS` (which is `,`). You can fix that with `RS="[,\n]"` if you have GNU awk.

Comment: I'm glad you noticed that, thank you! There is no need to change the code. Just adding the `-n` argument to `echo` averts this issue.

Comment: You're welcome. That would just create a new issue though because then what's being output by echo isn't a valid text line per POSIX (all lines must end in a newline) and so you're creating undefined behavior trying to run a text-processing tool on it. You work around the problem with `echo 'foo,'` to make sure the string ends with a comma.

Comment: Well, I know you are right about POSIX definition of a line, but awk deals with any collection of character, letting us describe how to input and output the data (namely, using `RS`, `FS`, `ORS` and `OFS` variables). I see no harm piping that to awk. In the end, the output is a valid POSIX line. Maybe I could have used `printf` instead, and treat line breaks in a different way, but, for now, I'll leave the code untouch.

Comment: Per the POSIX standard for awk (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) "Input files to the awk program from any of the following sources **shall be text files**" (emphasis mine) so YMMV.